# Error: Not running on server.close()

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

I have an error Not running only when I start my app.js on my server, it works on localhost.

My code is there : [Github](https://github.com/NahisWayard/summoner-infos)

```
Error: Not running
at Server.close (net.js:1233:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Nahis_Wayard/summoner-infos/app.js:13:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

Edit: I remove the 'server.close()' and now it works everywhere

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Looks like your `app.js` is closing a server that was not running. Show us that code.

Comment: The github link has died, so this question isn't understandable anymore. I'd suggest either copying the relevant code in so people can continue to learn from it, or closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app.js`, this code `var server = http.createServer(app);` is used.

However, the [`http.createServer()`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener) is *async* function, it returns a new instance of `http.Server`, and `http.server` inherits from `net.Server` and has the additional `events`.

So call `server.close()` could cause the error `Error: Not running` in your case.

Here is one sample codes shown the `close()` is invoked.

```
var server = http.createServer( (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('okay');
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1', () => {
    // other operations here

    server.close();
});
```